# Safe deployment of GAE apps

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to make sure that when I update my GAE site that it does not have any bad side effects for users who are currently using my site.

Does Google automatically make this a safe process, e.g. by:

- complete all pending requests
- temporarily delay new requests
- update code
- process new requests

Or does Google just terminate whatever is running and update the server code?

If the latter, any recommendations for doing a safe update?  Any other precautions for tasks in queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for some (usually quite short) time, your two versions are serving side-by-side. So some requests are on the new version, but some are still finishing up on the old version. Be sure to consider that when thinking about how your data structures will update.

Occasionally, I have received errors from a small number of users while deploying.

I think the safest way to do it is to deploy to a new 'version' that isn't the active one, then to change your default 'version' in the admin console. This ensures the quickest, cleanest, changeover.

Comment: And test the new version before you cut over ;-)  This also makes sure you have a few running instances before you to the cut over.

Comment: Thanks! For keeping track of versions, do you use a date or time stamp in the name or do you have another system?

Comment: My program has a version number already, so i use that - but a simple timestamp or such is good, too. Whichever is convenient for you