# GAE update app, how to avoid violent stop of long process?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a GAE apps that spawn some long process via an other module (managed by basic_scaling).

This long process handles correctly the DeadlineExceededError but spawning a defered method that will save the current state of the long process to be resumed later.

Today I discovered that when I do a `appcfg.py -A <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> update myapp/`, it abruptaly stops the long process. Just stop, no DeadlineExceededError (here goes my hope), nothing.

Is there some events triggered by GAE before stopping the app that would let me save the current state of my long process, write data to files (via s3, so a bit long), and re-queue the process to be re-run later ? (or something like this) ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Scaling types and instance classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes), both manual and basic scaling appear to behave identically from the instance shutdown prospective:

> As with manual scaling, an instance that is stopped with appcfg stop
>   or from the Cloud Platform Console) has 30 seconds to finish handling
>   requests before it is forcibly terminated.

I **assume** the same shutdown method is used when the app is updated.

And from [Shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown):

> There are two ways for an app to determine if a manual scaling
>   instance is about to be shut down. First, the is_shutting_down()
>   method from google.appengine.api.runtime starts returning true. Second
>   (and preferred), you can register a shutdown hook, as described below.
>
> When App Engine begins to shut down an instance, existing requests are
>   given 30 seconds to complete, and new requests immediately return 404.
>   If an instance is handling a request, App Engine pauses the request
>   and runs the shutdown hook. If there is no active request, App Engine
>   sends an /_ah/stop request, which runs the shutdown hook. The
>   /_ah/stop request bypasses normal handling logic and cannot be handled
>   by user code; its sole purpose is to invoke the shutdown hook. If you
>   raise an exception in your shutdown hook while handling another
>   request, it will bubble up into the request, where you can catch it.
>
> If you have enabled concurrent requests by specifying threadsafe: true
>   in app.yaml (which is the default), raising an exception from a
>   shutdown hook copies that exception to all threads. The following code
>   sample demonstrates a basic shutdown hook:
>
> ```
> from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
> from google.appengine.api import runtime
>
> def my_shutdown_hook():
>   apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.CancelApiCalls()
>   save_state()
>   # May want to raise an exception
>
> runtime.set_shutdown_hook(my_shutdown_hook)
> ```
>
> Alternatively, the following sample demonstrates how to use the
>   is_shutting_down() method:
>
> ```
> while more_work_to_do and not runtime.is_shutting_down():
>   do_some_work()
>   save_state()
> ```
>
> Note: It's important to recognize that the shutdown hook is not always
>   able to run before an instance terminates. In rare cases, an outage
>   can occur that prevents App Engine from providing 30 seconds of
>   shutdown time. Thus, we recommend periodically checkpointing the state
>   of your instance and using it primarily as an in-memory cache rather
>   than a reliable data store.

Based on my assumption above I expect these methods should work for your case as well, give them a try.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you replacing an existing `version` of your app (the default version).  When you do this, it doesn't gracefully handle existing processing.

Whenever I update the production version of my app, I do it in a new version.  I use the current date for my version name (e.g., 2016-05-13).  I then go to the Google cloud console and make that new version the default.  This way, the old version continues to run in parallel.

I asked a similar question a couple years ago that you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919134/safe-deployment-of-gae-apps).

Comment: Do you update the verison via some code ? or do you update it manually before pushing your code to production ?